# Need to filter in d3 based on a passed in value

Tags: json, d3.js, filtering

Im having some trouble filtering using d3 based on a passed in value

Im using JSON data and want to filter the data thats returned into the table based on a value

```
    "companyid": "151590",
    "receivingCompany": "1182316",
    "value": "145129619",
    "date": "22/01/2012",
    "int": "13"
```

Here is my D3

```
d3.json('transactions.json', function (error,transactions) {

function tabulate(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select('div#transaction-table').append('table').attr("class", function (d) {return 'table table-hover table-striped'})
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody');
var titles = [ "Borrowing Company", "Lending Company", "Amount (USD)", "Inception (DD/MM/YY)", "Interest (%)" ];

    // append the header row
    thead.append('tr')
      .selectAll('th')
      .data(titles).enter()
      .append('th')
  .text(function (titles) { return titles; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('tr');

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
      .data(function (row) {
        return columns.map(function (column) {
          return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
      })
      .enter()
      .append('td')
      .text(function (d) { return d.value; });

  return table;
}

// render the table(s)
tabulate(transactions, ['companyid', 'receivingCompany', 'value' , 'date'])


});
```

I want to filter the data returned based on the companyid.

```
  .filter(function(a) { return a.companyid == 137 })
```

This what ive found when searching online but this doesnt seem to work it just returns all the fields but only with "137" as a value and not the data that refers to 137.

Thanks

Comment: May be a.companyid is string and we are comparing with number, Try to use both sides same data type, i.e. convert a.companyid to number or use string '137' to compare.

Comment: Ive tried this to no avail :|(

Comment: could you make a fiddle with your sample data, and explain a little what you exactly want to get as result.